# Find deadlock in Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin, task, deadlock

I find the code snippet below has deadlock, although I already solved this problem by using read write lock, I still have no idea what exactly happens under the hood in Task.WhenAll that causes deadlock.

Problematic code:

```
   public async static Task<Dictionary<string, Log4SerialPort>> AvailableLog4SerialPorts()
        {
            var ports = App.SerialPortService.GetAvailablePorts();
            await Task.WhenAll(ports.Select(async port =>
            {
                if (!_availableLog4SerialPorts.ContainsKey(port.Path))
                {
                    var log4Port = new Log4SerialPort(port);
                    var isValid = await log4Port.Verify();
                    if (isValid)
                    {
                        _availableLog4SerialPorts.Add(port.Path, log4Port);
                    }

                }
            }));
            return _availableLog4SerialPorts;
        }
```

By adding read write lock, problem solved:

```
   public async static Task<Dictionary<string, Log4SerialPort>> AvailableLog4SerialPorts()
        {
            var ports = App.SerialPortService.GetAvailablePorts();
            await Task.WhenAll(ports.Select(async port =>
            {
                rwl.AcquireReaderLock(VERIFY_TIMEOUT);
                if (!_availableLog4SerialPorts.ContainsKey(port.Path))
                {
                    rwl.ReleaseReaderLock();
                    var log4Port = new Log4SerialPort(port);
                    var isValid = await log4Port.Verify();
                    if (isValid)
                    {
                        rwl.AcquireWriterLock(VERIFY_TIMEOUT);
                        _availableLog4SerialPorts.Add(port.Path, log4Port);
                        rwl.ReleaseWriterLock();
                    }

                }
            }));
            return _availableLog4SerialPorts;
        }
```

`_availableLog4SerialPorts` is a static field.

`log4Port.Verify()` doesn't share any static resources, it just does some time-consuming tasks.

It seems Task.WhenAll will lock the static resources automatically, but not sure how it works and the detailed blocking reason in this case.

Comment: if structures are not thread safe, then using them in a multi-threaded environment will have unintended and unforeseen consequences... without knowing the workings of every structure you are using then its nearly impossible for us to guess whats causing the problem, however glad you fixed it.. Do note though, `Dictionary` isn't thread safe to start with and who knows what `Log4SerialPort` does

Comment: You might have to go up the chain from `AvailableLog4SerialPorts`. How are you calling it?

Comment: You say, *I find the code snippet below has deadlock*. How do you know that?

Comment: @CodingYoshi @John @MichaelRandall `Log4SerialPort` is just like a wrapper of `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` and `AvailableLog4SerialPorts` is a static `Dictionary<string, Log4SerialPort>`. I think it is a deadlock it because after I added the read write lock manually, the problem solved. And I am also reading other posted issues, it seems Dictionary in multi-threaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a small program to reproduce this problem, and it seems the reason why the program is blocked is as what @Michael Randall said, `Dictionary` in multi-threaded environment may cause unintended behaviour. Followings are the screenshot of the test. Without locks, the program will block at any arbitrary point during execution.

[without locks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLfda.jpg)

[with locks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zPkO.jpg) (Sorry I still cannot embed images yet...)

Thanks for all your helps : )

Comment: Please mark your solution as answered. Helps other searching for questions to help on so they don't waste time on questions that are answered. Thanks!

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Will do it, the system does not allow me to accept my own answer yet.